# Prevent new line but allow enter (submit) in textarea (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `<textarea>` and I want users to edit what's already there and press enter to submit using an ajax call but also disable it going to a new line once enter is pressed. thanks

```js
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if (!$(".specialClass").is(":focus")) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.which == 13) {
      console.log('You pressed enter!');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You would use something like:

```
$('textarea').on('keyup keypress', function(e) {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if (keyCode === 13) { 
    e.preventDefault();

    // Ajax code here

    return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

> i want users to edit whats already there and press enter to submit using an ajax call but also disable it going to a new line once enter is pressed

Using your coding design, a slight reshape to your code should make the job:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if($(".specialClass").is(":focus")){
    if(e.which == 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
      let text_value = $(".specialClass").val()
      console.log('Sending Ajax with text',text_value);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this help you.

```js
$(document).keypress('.specialClass', function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('You pressed enter!');
  }
});
```

```css
.specialClass {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="specialClass">
  This is my text
  with some lines
  bye
</textarea>
```